# Use conditions in views rewrite

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that shows an overview of "experiences".
The problem I am having is they switch HTML on every row.

so the first will be:

Image text

then the second will be:

Text Image

I tried using conditionals in the rewrite result. 
But they seem to not work as shown below:

[image]

This outputs:

[image]

Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

By setting field_my_link to show as URLs / plain text I was able to quickly get the result I needed, to point the URL of the title to an offsite URL if it has data, and keep it to the NID url otherwise. view_node is a view field of the URL

```
{% if field_my_link|length > 0 %}
<a href="{{ field_my_link }}">{{ title }}</a>
{% else %}
<a href="{{ view_node }}">{{ title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

This worked quickly and effectively as a rewrite. Although I would rather not have a rewrite stored as config in views, it was a quick and reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is from Drupal 7 post, long time ago but I guess the methodology is still the same.

Basically in your views template you can specify that logic.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1932102#comment-7182640

```
if (row is even)
  // display order 1
else {
  // display order 2
}
```

Update: There is port of the views conditional module available on github.

https://github.com/anandtoshniwal93/views_conditional/blob/master/README.md
You can reuse it in your view like that....

```
Views Conditional field (if row is even)

  print rewrite field 1 (which is the first combination order)

Viws Conditional field (if row is odd)

  print rewrite field 2 (which is the second combination order)
```

Comment: I'm using the port of the module available on GitHub it works well in my Flexslider slideshow.

Comment: UPDATE: this module https://github.com/anandtoshniwal93/views_conditional/blob/master/README.md doesn't handle translations :(